# Parse text from a screen grab

Tags: c#, java, parsing, screenshot, ocr

Not sure the best way to explain this but i'll give it a shot. I'm trying to find a way to parse text/numbers from a screen grab in either C# or Java - whichever provides the easiest way, but preferably java.

An example would be as follows. You have a website/document/application with a block of text. You can take a screenshot of the specific area which contains this text. Once the screenshot has been taken you can extract a string from it containing the relevant characters.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: trying to break another captcha? :-)))

Comment: lol..its mainly for reading the hand index in a pokerstars game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Tessnet2 a .NET 2.0 Open Source OCR assembly using Tesseract engine](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/).

Comment: Link you suggested is broken.

Comment: Nice. Tessnet in deed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking a screenshot it will be saved into an image file. You can use OCR image tools to break it down into text, but it's not 100% always in the conversion. Parsing text and/or numbers is just basic code in C# or Java.

Answer (score 1):

[FreeOCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is best out of all the OCRs I've tried.